# Creating a parser for an ics file

Tags: objective-c, icalendar

I am trying to create a parser so that i can load data from a .ics file and save in to some kind of array so it can then be loaded in to the Kal library.

The format of the ics is vCalendar and looks something like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20130207T123200
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20121012T130000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20121012T140000
SUMMARY:TEst
LOCATION:London
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:steve@msn.com
END:VEVENT
```

I've looked around everywhere but cant seem to find a technique to do this, can someone give me an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

libical (http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/) and/or `NSScanner` should help

Comment: First google hit for "libical example" links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954750/parse-vcalendar-ics-with-objective-c which includes sample code