# Open .ics file in iOS App

Tags: ios, icalendar

I need to open a .ics file in my app.

I tried to open it like this:

```
NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myIcsName" withExtension:@"ics"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:path];
```

But nothing is happening.

How do I open the .ics file?

Comment: You can't pass a file URL to the `UIApplication openURL:` method. What are you actually trying to do here? What do you want to happen with the ics file?

Comment: @rmaddy I want the user to be able to view the ics file in the calendar app.

Comment: Looking at the results of the following search, it seems no one knows how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+ics+open+calendar

Comment: @rmaddy That makes me the 1st one ;)

Comment: Strange because I thought several of those other questions indicated that using `UIDocumentInteractionController` didn't offer the Calendar app as an option. That certainly was my first thought. Good to know it works as expected.

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just used the following code:

```
- (IBAction)displayICS:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"ics"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *dc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    dc.delegate = self;
    [dc presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
-(UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This wont allow you to open from a URL, only a file.

Comment: This allow to view event information but how to add event to calendar? there is no option on UIDocumentInteractionController to add event on calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I have found there are two projects that enable you to open an ICS file and get events, dates and other information out of it as Objective-C objects.

MXLCalendarManager seems to be a bit further along and will allow you to pull out the events from the ICS file search on date and add the events to the users iOS calendar.  This might be what your looking for. [GitHub Project MXLCalendarManager](https://github.com/KiranPanesar/MXLCalendarManager)  It also supports writing new ICS files.

I've created a project that uses the libical library written in C to parse the complete ICS file.  The project is still in the early stages and could use some more tender care before its ready to just drop into a project.  You can check it out at [Github Project XbICalendar](https://github.com/ahalls/XbICalendar/)  More details on libical can be found at [GitHub Project libical](https://github.com/libical/libical)